# Deducing a single variance from a covariance matrix

Tags: estimation, covariance

I use linear discriminant analysis and I want to compare different assumptions about the covariance matrix. I want to explore what happens if I use a covariance matrix proportional to the identity matrix although my data does not come from such a covariance matrix. I get the following sample covariance matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
        \sigma_1^2 & b         \\
       b & \sigma_2^2           \\
     \end{bmatrix}
$$

However, I do not want to use this matrix. I want to use something like:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
        \sigma^2 & 0         \\
       0 & \sigma^2           \\
     \end{bmatrix}
$$

So how can I estimate $\sigma^2$ from the first matrix. 
Is this correct?
$$
\sigma^2 = (\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)/2
$$

Comment: Have you considered an intermediate variant where the covariance matrix is taken to be $\text{diag}(\sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2)$ so that the variances of the two data components are the same but the data are components are treated as uncorrelated or independent instead of having nonzero covariance $b$?

Comment: When I use $diag(\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2)$, how will the variances of the two data components be the same?

Comment: They wont. Your _data_ is of the form $(x_i,y_i)$ where you are modeling the samples as realizations of random variables $X$ and $Y$ with variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ respectively and covariance $b$. You now want to treat $X$ and $Y$ as _uncorrelated_ random variables with common variance $\sigma^2$. This is fine, and if you want to do so, you might want to estimate the common variance from $2n$ sample values (the $x_i$ and the $y_i$) rather than as $(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)/2$. _My_ suggestion was to use the data and (estimated?) variances as is, and simply ignore the covariance.